# PHP is failing with php_pgsql.dll on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I use PHP 7 and postgres and until a while ago I got this error but it did not give more problems than the warning, I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Core Warning

Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pgsql.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pgsql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Linux doesn't use `.dll` files (it uses `.so` files in a similar way) so you can likely replace `.dll` with `.so` for what appears to be your custom (and much older) version of PHP.

You can also get a much newer and easier to use version of PHP using:

```
sudo apt install php
sudo apt install php-pgsql
```

Now you should have a working version of PHP that is up-to-date and patched with postgres enabled.